# Regex Pattern to find 5 digit number where the first 2 digits are given?

Tags: excel, regex, vba

So I'm using a Regex function on VBA to extract 5 digit numbers.
What I have below is working for me so far.

It extracts 5 digit numbers such as '12345' or alphanumeric characters such as 'a12345'.
However, I want it to extract 5 digit characters where we'll know what the first 2 digits are, such as 12xxx, or 45xxx.

How would I specify what the first 2 digits should be?

```
Function Digits(r As String) As String
Dim m
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "\b\d{5}\b|^(?![0-9]{6})[0-9a-zA-Z]{6}$"
    .Global = False
    If Not .test(r) Then Exit Function
    For Each m In .Execute(r)
        Multi5 = Multi5 & m & ", "
    Next
Digits = Left(Digits, Len(Digits) - 2)
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Like this? `\b12\d{3}\b|^(?![0-9]{6})12[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}$`

Comment: I think the "rule" will apply to the first alternative, `.Pattern = "\b(?:12|45)\d{3}\b|^(?![0-9]{6})[0-9a-zA-Z]{6}$"`. However, `Digits = Left(Digits, Len(Digits) - 2)` is suspicious, you are not initializing `Digits` before using this.

Comment: You probably meant to use `Multi5` in penultimate  line. And you should declare it inside function. Put `Option Explicit` at top of your code module to force this declaration. `r` should also be passed as `ByVal` in signature.

Answer (score 1):

Modify .Global = False to .Global = True

```
Function Digits(r As String) As String
    Dim m As Object, matchs As Object
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        '.Pattern = "\b\d{5}\b|^(?![0-9]{6})[0-9a-zA-Z]{6}$"
        .Pattern = "12\d{3}"
        .Global = True
        If Not .test(r) Then Exit Function
        Set matchs = .Execute(r)
        For Each m In matchs
            multi5 = multi5 & m & ", "
        Next
    Digits = Left(multi5, Len(multi5) - 2)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I would keep the word boundaries to prevent partial matches `\b12\d{3}\b`